# Pan & Change Zoom to show Fusion Tables Query Results in Google Maps JavaScript API V3

Tags: google-maps, google-fusion-tables

I've created this map --  https://s3.amazonaws.com/pdb.files/lookup_auto2.html -- using Google Fusion Tables and Google Maps API. I'm attempting to modify the code so that the map will pan and  zoom after executing the query. It seems that I need to use either the fitBounds function to display the bounds of the results, or something simpler like this:

```
// Change the center and zoom of the map
      map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
      map.setZoom(10);
```

I'd prefer the second option so that I can set a consistent zoom level for each query.  Any pointers or references for completing this are much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Add a spatial search to your code:**

FUSION TABLES allows **ST_INTERSECT** to be performed
full reference:
http://code.google.com/apis/fusiontables/docs/developers_reference.html#Select
(see `<spatial_condition>` )

```
      // OPTIONAL: find the new map bounds, and run a spatial query to return
  // Fusion Tables results within those bounds. 
  sw = map.getBounds().getSouthWest();
  ne = map.getBounds().getNorthEast();
  layer.setOptions({
    query: {
      select: 'lat',
      from: tableid,
      where: "ST_INTERSECTS(lat, RECTANGLE(LATLNG(" + sw.lat() + "," + sw.lng() + "), LATLNG(" + ne.lat() + "," + ne.lng() + ")))"
    }
  });
```

Full code:
http://gmaps-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/fusiontables/search_and_zoom.html (view source)